# Money formats with commas in an array

Tags: php, arrays, escaping

My PHPstorm is throwing a wobbly with the formats of an array. Surprsingly I've found no direct answer to how to have this array formatted. I've tried the following, I'm surprised the single quotes don't work and then the other two but no luck...

```
$array = array(’$2,000,000’,’$3,000,000’,’$4,000,000’);
$array = array("$2,000,000","$3,000,000","$4,000,000");
$array = array("\$2,000,000","\$3,000,000","\$4,000,000");
```

The manual doesn't have commas as escapable. Given that the array is for HTML ouput only I could put

```
$array = array("&#362&#44000&#44000","&#36$3&#44000&#44000","&#364&#44000&#44000");
```

but i want to **LEARN HOW TO DO IT properly**!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single quotes don't work because what you have here are NOT single quotes, but rather curly apostrophes:

```
// Incorrect - not real single quotes:
$array = array(’$2,000,000’,’$3,000,000’,’$4,000,000’);

// Correct single quotes:
$array = array('$2,000,000','$3,000,000','$4,000,000');
```

Assuming you may have copy/pasted this from somewhere, always beware curly quotes when working with code.  Some CMS' and frameworks will convert them for display purposes, but doing so breaks the code for copy/pasters.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the problem is that I don't use an English keyboard. My Italian keyboard doesn't have... single quotes or curly brackets for example... these and other characters make way for all the accented letters we use. However programs might, as you say, display what I wanted but if I haven't actually flipped keyboard values then this happens...

Answer (score 5):

You're using incorrect quotes:

```
$array = array(’$2,000,000’,’$3,000,000’,’$4,000,000’);
               ^--        ^-^---       ^---etc....
```

Those aren't proper quotes, and should be a `'` or `"` character instead.

Comment: If anyone ever solves the artificial intelligence problem, it'll be Microsoft, because they've already mastered artificial stupidity.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. Explained why this happened to @michael - i think they are called 'backticks'....

Comment: No, backticks are like backslashes, they lean topleft->bottom right. Usually it's over the tab key, paired with ~